# Tcl/Tk: horizontal xscrollbar can not shrink as y scollbar

Tags: scrollbar, tcl, tk-toolkit

In the following example code:

```
proc push_button {} {
    set name [.ent get]
    .txt insert end "Hello, $name."
}
frame .frm -relief groove
label .lab -text "Enter name:"
entry .ent
button .but -text "Push Me" -command "push_button"
frame .textarea
text .txt -width 20 -height 10 \
    -yscrollcommand ".srl_y set" -xscrollcommand ".srl_x set"
scrollbar .srl_y -command ".txt yview" -orient v
scrollbar .srl_x -command ".txt xview" -orient h
pack .lab -in .frm
pack .ent -in .frm
pack .frm
pack .but
grid .txt   -in .textarea -row 1 -column 1
grid .srl_y -in .textarea -row 1 -column 2 -sticky ns
grid .srl_x -in .textarea -row 2 -column 1 -sticky ew
pack .textarea
```

Push the button `Push Me`, new text string will be added into the textbox. And in `.txt insert end "Hello, $name."` there is no new line `\n` symbol. So it should form a very long string.

My understanding is as the string goes longer, the horizontal scollbar should change and shrink correspondingly. But xscollbar can not work as expected.

I need such effect in my tool. So any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is because of text wrapping. The default text wrapping mode seems to be `char` (the text will be split into more lines when the width limit is reached, and it will split on a character basis).

Change the following line to get the behaviour you were expecting to see:

```
text .txt -width 20 -height 10 \
    -yscrollcommand ".srl_y set" -xscrollcommand ".srl_x set" -wrap none
```

I added `-wrap none` to the end.